# Drawing multiple box plots from a file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, wrapfigure, boxplot

I've got data in the following format

```
n lw lq m uq uw
50 200 209 237 327 569
100 376 379 386 390 391
150 ...
...
```

Where `lw = lower whisker`, `lq = lower quartile`, etc.

I want to plot each box against `n` on the x axis and end up with a figure that looks something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [togaware.com](http://www.togaware.com/datamining/survivor/rplot-boxplot-by-month.png))</sub>

I've been trying to modify an existing graph that was plotting the non-boxed data, but I can't find a way to configure it that doesn't result in LaTeX failing to compile.

```
\pgfplotstableread{code/tree/results.dat}\loadedtable

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
      xlabel={Size of Tree $n$},
      ylabel={Time $\mu$s},
      width=11cm,
      height=10cm
    ]
    \addplot [box plot] table[x=n,y=???] from \loadedtable;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test Results}
  \label{fig:tree-results-1}
\end{figure}
```

How can I specify the box plot limits using a data file rather than a prepared set of fixed values?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know. However, in this case, my existing code/environment is pretty much irrelevant, rather I'm just looking for a canonical example, rather than asking for a fix.

Comment: You are asking people to plot limits from a data file. A MWE will give people something to work with rather than asking the to write everything from scratch for you. It saves people time and, as I said, makes it much more likely that some one will help you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Let me clarify then, what should my minimum working example show? I don't understand how to draw a box plot from a file. I could include a MWE of a scatter graph, but I don't see how that would help anyone.

Comment: It seems the boxplot was not intended to interface with pgfplotstable.  It looks like you are going to need a foreach loop and a whole lot of \pgfplotstablegetelem calls.